# How can I link a fortran program with a module dependency for use in c++?

Tags: c++, fortran, g++, gfortran

fortranModule.f90

```
module fortranModule
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    contains

    subroutine print_f90()
        implicit none
        write(*,*) "This is a message from Fortran 90."
    end subroutine print_f90
end module fortranModule
```

fortranProgram.f90

```
program fortranProgram
    use iso_c_binding
    use fortranModule
    implicit none

    !Do some work as input for print_f90()
    call print_f90()
end program fortranProgram
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
    extern void fortranProgram(void);
}

int main(void) {
    fortranProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to compile with the following steps:

```
gfortran -c fortranModule.f90 fortranProgram.f90

g++ -c main.cpp

g++ main.o fortranModule.o fortraProgram.o -o main -lgfortran
```

gives

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    main.o
    fortranProgram.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

How can I link a fortran program with module dependencies to a c++ program? Is this possible? Do I need to rewrite fortranProgram.f90 as a module or subroutine? Maybe there is a naming scheme similar to *__modulename_MOD_subroutinename*?

Comment: Your Fortran entry point needs to be a function or subroutine, not the regular program Fortran entrypoint. You are trying to link into one executable, two main entry points, one in C++ and one in Fortran.

Comment: I thought that may be the case.

Comment: @M.A, I can modify fortranProgram and pull it in as a module. How do I pull it in as a single subroutine?

Comment: You need to add a C binding declaration to your fortran subroutine signature `subroutine print_f90()  bind(c,name='print_f90')`. Then if you compile only the module, you should be able to reference it in your C++.

Comment: If you managed to get it working, I would at least add it as an update to the question or an answer if appropriate.

Comment: Yes. I plan to answer with both subroutine and module example.

Answer (score 0):

Changing fortranProgram.f90 to

```
subroutine call_print_f90(num) bind(c, name='call_print_f90')
    use iso_c_binding
    use fortranModule
    implicit none

    call print_f90(num)
end subroutine call_print_f90
```

and changing main.cpp to

```
extern "C" {
    extern void call_print_f90(void);
}

int main(void) {
    call_print_f90();
    return 0;
}
```

resolves the problem of having two conflicting "mains".

Below is a solution in which fortranProgram.f90 is refactored as a module.

fortranProgram.f90

```
module fortranProgram
    use iso_c_binding
    use fortranModule
    implicit none
    contains

    subroutine call_print_f90() bind(c, name='call_print_f90')
        call print_f90(num)
    end subroutine call_print_f90
end module fortranProgram
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
    extern void call_print_f90(void);
}

int main(void) {
    call_print_f90();
    return 0;
}
```